# Incorrect output after defining args in launch.json in vscode

Tags: python, json, vscode-debugger, huggingface

I'm currently trying to follow [this](https://huggingface.co/docs/diffusers/training/controlnet) huggingface tutorial on how to train a controlnet.

I set up my machine and everything is running - in order to be able to check what's happening I created a launch.json file to run it with the debugger in order to have an easier way to understand what happend for the case that anything breaks.

my launch.json:

```
{
    // Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes.
    // Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
    // For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Python: Current File",
            "type": "python",
            "request": "launch",
            "module": "accelerate.commands.launch",
            "args": [
                "./train_controlnet.py",
                "--pretrained_model_name_or_path", "stabilityai/stable-diffusion-2-1",
                "--output_dir", "/home/chris/tmp/hf_test",
                "--resolution", "512",
                "--learning_rate", "1e-5",
                "--validation_image", "./conditioning_image_1.png", "./controlnet/conditioning_image_2.png",
                "--validation_prompt", "\"red circle with blue background\"", "\"cyan circle with brown background\"",
                "--train_batch_size", "12",
                "--gradient_accumulation_steps", "4",
                "--mixed_precision", "fp16",
                "--enable_xformers_memory_efficient_attention",
                "--dataset_name", "fusing/fill50k",
            ],
            "console": "integratedTerminal",
            "justMyCode": false
        }
    ]
}
```

The command the debugger creates to run it:

```
cd /home/chris/repos/diffusers ; /usr/bin/env /home/chris/programs/miniconda3/envs/diffusers/bin/python /home/chris/.vscode/extensions/ms-python.python-2023.20.0/pythonFiles/lib/python/debugpy/adapter/../../debugpy/launcher 41471 -- -m accelerate.commands.launch ./train_controlnet.py --pretrained_model_name_or_path stabilityai/stable-diffusion-2-1 --output_dir /home/chris/tmp/hf_test --resolution 512 --learning_rate 1e-5 --validation_image ./conditioning_image_1.png ./conditioning_image_2.png --validation_prompt \"red\ circle\ with\ blue\ background\" \"cyan\ circle\ with\ brown\ background\" --train_batch_size 12 --gradient_accumulation_steps 4 --mixed_precision fp16 --enable_xformers_memory_efficient_attention --dataset_name fusing/fill50k
```

My problem is the `--validation_prompt` argument which I can't get to be formatted correctly. Basically I'd need to remove the backslashes, which I don't know why they're there.

```
--validation_prompt \"red\ circle\ with\ blue\ background\" \"cyan\ circle\ with\ brown\ background\"
```

Let me know if I need or can add something to make my problem clearer.

Help is much appreciated !

Comment: looks like VS Code handles the shell quoting just fine without you having to worry about it. try replacing your `"\"red circle with blue background\""` with `"red circle with blue background"`.